# Как правильно вынести реализацию в другой класс

Tags: java, android, firebase

Всем привет.
Вопрос такой, у меня есть готовый код авторизации пользователя через `FirebaseAuth` все в принципе просто, все работает и я подключил. Но я хочу вынести все это из активити, в отдельный модуль. И не получается это оформить. В идеале, это должно работать так, что в активити просто вызываем метод `signIn()` и все остальное уже должно быть сделано в отдельном классе, например `googleAuth`. Я все перенес, но проблема в том, что `googleAuth` методы, которые предлагает `firebase` требует `activity`. Так как есть `onActivityResult` + `startActivityForResult`.

Я понимаю, что вопрос новичка. Я реализовывал, когда требовались контекст. Но с активити еще не имел дела. Или в таких случаях не получится все вызывать из другого класса и когда идет работа с активити все должно быть реализовано в самом активити?

Вот код с методами

```
public class AuthPage extends BaseActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    @BindView(R.id.sign_in_button)
    SignInButton googleSignInBth;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    GoogleAuthenticationUtil googleAuthenticationUtil;

    Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.auth_activity);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        googleAuthenticationUtil = new GoogleAuthenticationUtil( , mGoogleApiClient, this);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        //TODO In module
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        //TODO In module
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.sign_in_button)
    void googleBtnAuth(View view) {
        signIn();
    }

    private void signIn(){
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountsListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.v("Tag", "Sign in failed");
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v("Tag", "On Connection Failde: "+ connectionResult.toString());
    }

    private void signOut(){
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Если вопрос уже рассматривался или задан не корректно, большая просьба указать мне на ошибку. Это позволит мне искать лучше и не задавать глупых вопросов.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Создать отдельный класс для работы с firebase, добавить необходимые методы и т.д., но поскольку методы firebase требуют Activity, все равно придется либо передавать ссылку на Activity, либо каким то образом вызывать из Activity.
2. Оставить как есть сейчас
3. Создать интерфейс с необходимыми методами, создать класс для работы c firebase, в Activity имплементить созданный интерфейс, создать объект этого класса, передать туда ссылку на интерфейс и дергать уже методы интерфеса.